# How to create vectors dynamically in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector, initialization

I am trying to initialize vectors depending upon user input. For example, if user provide `n=4` then I have to create 4 vectors of varying sizes.
As for vectors syntax is :

```
vector<int> v1(x);
```

So, similarly I want to create `v2`,`v3` and `v4` named vectors.

I am confused. How can I do this ?

Comment: You can't do that. But you could have a *vector of vectors*.

Comment: Are all vectors of different sizes? Then just do it the same for them separately with their respective size? If they are all the same, you could have a vector of vectors, where you initialize the vectors through copying, as in `vector<vector<type>> v(4, vector<type>(x));`

Comment: The data and size that is going to be stored inside those 4 vectors is dynamic. And requirement is that user can query value at any index of any of those 4 vectors.

Comment: You can have a map of type `std::map<std::string, std::vector<T>>`, then consider the key is the vector name

Comment: @yksisarvinen But the size is dynamic for all the 4 vectors and it is dependent upon the user input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The names of individual vectors `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, ... are defined at compile time.  If you want to have a dynamic number of vectors, you need  a `vector` of `vector`s, e.g.:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vs;
```

or if you already know the number of vectors n that you want:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vs(n);
```

Then, instead of using `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, you'd use `vs[0]`, `vs[1]`, `vs[2]`, and your code could use dynamically a vector `v[i]` where `i` is a variable or an expression.

You can add a vector to `vs` with `emplace_back`/`push_back` or `resize`:

```
vs.emplace_back();

//or

vs.push_back({});

// or

vs.push_back(std::vector<int>());

// or

vs.resize(4);
```

In the latter case `vs` will contain four empty vectors (or the first 4 existing vectors if vs already had more than 4 vectors).

And you can add elements to the inner vectors as usually, e.g.:

```
vs[0].push_back(42);

vs[2].resize(x);
```

After that the first vector will have length one and the third vector will have length `x`.

Or you can insert a vector with size `x` directly after the last vector:

```
vs.emplace_back(x);

// or

vs.push_back({x});

// or

vs.push_back(std::vector<int>(x));
```

Elements can then be accessed with double indices, e.g.

```
vs[1][14]
```

reads the 15th element of the 2nd vector.